# how to select by index from a bigr.frame?

Tags: r, biginsights, bigr

In standard r, I can select by index using something like the following:

```
newdf <- df[1:4,]
```

However, if I try the above on a bigr.frame, I get:

```
Error: BigR[bigr.frame.[]]: The given filtering condition must be a logical bigr.vector.
```

The documentation for `[ {bigr}` is as follows:

> **Description**
>
> Filter rows and project columns of a dataset
>
> **Usage**
>
> "["(x, i, j, ..., drop = TRUE)
>
> **Arguments**
>
> **x** (bigr.frame or bigr.matrix) the object being operated on. If x is a
>   bigr.frame or bigr.csv.matrix, both filtering and projection are
>   supported. If x is a bigr.binary.matrix, only projections are
>   supported.
>
> **i** (bigr.vector) a logical operation that represents the filtering
>   condition (only for bigr.frame and bigr.matrix objects)
>
> **j** (character or integer) a vector representing columns to be
>   projected. These could be column ids (i.e., integers) or column names
>   (i.e., characters)
>
> **drop** in the case of projecting one single column, parameter drop determines
>   whether the result should be a bigr.vector (drop=TRUE) or a bigr.frame
>   (drop=FALSE). Default value is drop=TRUE.
>
> **Value**
>
> the derived bigr.frame, bigr.matrix, or bigr.vector
>
> **See Also**
>
> bigr.frame bigr.matrix
>
> **Examples**
>
> `air[air$UniqueCarrier %in% c("UA", "HA"), c(1,2,3,5:9)]`
>
> `air[, c("Origin", "Dest")]`
>
> `air[air$Dest == "SFO", 17]`
>
> `class(air[, 17, drop=FALSE])`
>
> `class(air[, 17, drop=TRUE])`

It isn't clear to me if I can select by index.  Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as.data.frame function.

Refer: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.bigr.doc/doc/frame_as.data.frame.html?lang=en

airfile <- system.file("extdata", "airline.zip", package="bigr")

airfile <- unzip(airfile, exdir = tempdir())

airR <- read.csv(airfile, stringsAsFactors=F)

air <- as.bigr.frame(airR)

airdf <- as.data.frame(air)

newdf <- airdf[1:4,]

newdf

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter expects the logical condition and second argument represent the columns.

The same functionality you are looking can be done by head(frame, no#OfRows)

```
airfile <- system.file("extdata", "airline.zip", package="bigr")
airfile <- unzip(airfile, exdir = tempdir())
airR <- read.csv(airfile, stringsAsFactors=F)
air <- as.bigr.frame(airR)
head(air, 4)
```

Refer: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.tut.doc/doc/tut_Less_BigR_Stat2.html

Comment: Thanks Nisanth, head will work for some use cases, but not all.  Would you be able to provide an example of the first approach, e.g selecting rows 3:4 of the airfile dataset?